# Jasperserver timestamp input control does not update value on schedule

Tags: datetime, parameters, timestamp, schedule, jasperserver

I'm facing some issues with jasperserver timestamp input control (java.sql.Timestamp), the Date/Time parameter works fine in JasperReport Studio and also works fine when running the report one time in jasperserver, but the parameter is not updated to the current date time when the report is on a schedule, so the report came out as an empty pdf file because there is no data on that timestamp.

Or is there a way to evaluate the timestamp parameter at report generation/schedule

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a solution to the problem.

To create a dynamic timestamp parameter, first we need to get the timestamp from the main query of the report (SELECT NOW() AS datetime) then we map this field to the parameter

create parameter REPORT_DATE (type java.sql.Timestamp)
then in all the tables or charts, we map the field to the parameter
using this syntax :
$P{REPORT_DATE} == null ? $F{datetime}.getTime() : $P{REPORT_DATE}.getTime()

(using .getTime() here because my database is using Unix Timestamp, if you need just the ddMMYYYY hh:mm:ss then exclude this)

with this way if the user insert the REPORT_DATE input control manually we will be using the REPORT_DATE from the user, if not then we will be using the timestamp from the main query, this way the timestamp can be dynamically updated on scheduled time